# SQL Injection in PL/SQL - myth or fact?

Tags: sql, plsql, code-injection

I am trying to hack my PL/SQL code. We create the PL/SQL procedure that opens and fetch the cursor. By our standard we did create a dynamic SQL statement, but we are unable to inject the OR 1=1 condition.

I did prepare a http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a62a3/5 demo, where you can try to inject the code.

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_documents (p_document_id IN DOCUMENTS.DOCUMENT_ID%TYPE)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
    p_rs SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('------ INPUT VALUES ------');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('p_document_id: ' || p_document_id);

    OPEN p_rs FOR 
        SELECT DOCUMENT_ID, '(' || MY_FIELD || ')' FROM DOCUMENTS WHERE DOCUMENT_ID = '' ||  p_document_id  || '';
    RETURN p_rs;
END;
```

We tried to inject the code in p_document_id parameter. We set it to:

```
 document_refcur_local:=get_documents('10'' OR 1=1; -- ');
```

but we were unable to select all records. Could you please let me know what am I doing it wrong?

Comment: `'' ||  p_document_id  || ''` doesn't really do anything. It just returns `p_document_id` (with two empty strings concatenated to it).

Comment: I am not sure but looked to me as if you are only sending a parameter instead of concatenating an SQL statement in the front end. (You are dynamically changing the parameter but the SQL statement itself is not a dynamic string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not in fact a dynamic statement and so is not vulnerable to an injection.

If you built this string from a front-end with string concatenation of the p_document_id outside of the SQL query - then sent it to SQL, it would be vulnerable, but you cannot do the injection in the SQL query itself (Unless building a string then running it, i.e. a dynamic query, which yours is not doing)

A dynamic query vulnerable to injection would look more like;

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM DOCUMENTS WHERE DOCUMENT_ID = ''' + someUserInput + ''''
```

And you could inject by passing as someUserInput something like

```
' OR 1=1; --
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please explain why is not a dynamic statement? We did use a concatenation?  What does defines the dynamic statement?

Comment: @Gico - A dynamic statement builds the statement itself as a string, then executes that string. Your statement only dynamically changes A PARAMETER, not the query itself. Looks at my edit for an example...

Comment: @Gico The point is that you're not concatenating strings in order to create a string containing SQL code; you're merely concatenating strings inside your (static) SQL.

Comment: Still wouldn't work. Oracle won't allow a `;` inside a string used for EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Answer (score 4):

If you want to succeed at SQL injection your SELECT statement needs to be specified as a character string to which you concatenate your document ID string, which contains the condition to be added. Here's your code, rewritten:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_DOCUMENTS (p_document_id IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
  p_rs SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('------ INPUT VALUES ------');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('p_document_id: ' || p_document_id);

  OPEN p_rs FOR 
    'SELECT DOCUMENT_ID, ''('' || MY_FIELD || '')'' FROM DOCUMENTS WHERE DOCUMENT_ID = ''' ||  p_document_id  || '''';

  RETURN p_rs;
END GET_DOCUMENTS;
```

Answer (score 2):

An example:

```
create table documents (id, value) as 
(
    select 1, 'x' from dual union all
    select 2, 'x' from dual union all
    select 3, 'y' from dual
)
```

A vulnerable function:

```
create or replace function countDocs(pValue IN varchar2) return number is
    vRetVal number;
begin
    execute immediate 'select count(*) from documents where value = ''' || pValue || ''''
    into vRetVal;
    return vRetVal;
end;
```

What you can do:

```
SQL> select countDocs('y') from dual;

COUNTDOCS('Y')
--------------
             1

SQL> select countDocs('y'' or ''a''=''a') from dual;

COUNTDOCS('Y''OR''A''=''A')
---------------------------
                          3
```

A safe way could be with bind variables:

```
create or replace function countDocsSafe(pValue IN varchar2) return number is
    vRetVal number;
begin
    execute immediate 'select count(*) from documents where value = :bindVar'
    into vRetVal
    using pValue ;
    return vRetVal;
end;
```

Which gives:

```
SQL> select countDocsSafe('y') from dual;

COUNTDOCSSAFE('Y')
------------------
                 1

SQL> select countDocsSafe('y'' or ''a''=''a') from dual;

COUNTDOCSSAFE('Y''OR''A''=''A')
-------------------------------
                              0
```